# Null Pointer Exception while trying to use the settext function

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have 2 navigation tabs and each navigation tab contains a listview. Each listview is made up of several components including a textview which i am trying to edit.

I'm trying to settext for a text view in the class that defines each fragment but i get a null pointer exception.

The following are some code excerpts:

View Pager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/titleTaskList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Each Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Each listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="address"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

....
```

This is the code for my adapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public ListFragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new ArabicFragment();
            case 1:
                return new EnglishFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }
}
```

and in this class i define the tabs:

```
public class TaskListAndOptionsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private static ActionBar actionBar;
    private static Context context; 

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Arabic", "English"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list_and_options);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.titleTaskList);

        actionBar = getActionBar();

        getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

             @Override
             public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
             }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
         });
}
```

....

and finally in this class i am trying to settext (this class is for each fragment)

```
public class ArabicFragment extends ListFragment {
public static ArrayList<String> taskListAr = new ArrayList<String>();
private static Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("changing layout","arabic");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasklistar, container, false);  
    return rootView;
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        displayTaskList();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_itemar,R.id.title, taskListAr);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
}


    TextView taskDetails = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.taskdetails);
    taskDetails.setText("trial");
```

....

if this is not the right place to call the settext then where should it be called?

Comment: Put your `.setText(....)` in your `onCreateView(.....)` and try like   `TextView taskDetails = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.taskdetails);`

Comment: You can use getSupportActionBar().setText("Your text");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write in **onCreateView** method.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("changing layout","arabic");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasklistar, container, false);
        TextView taskDetails = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.taskdetails);
        taskDetails.setText("trial");
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Thing is fragment_tasklistar only contains the listview definition but the initialization of the items in the listview is in another layout xml as seen above, is that what is causing the error?

Comment: You have to implement Adapter for load data into Listview..[check this](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Displaying_Data_with_ListView_and_BaseAdapter_%28Android%29)

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not use the link you have provided however you did set me on the right path. I used this link: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html and i developed a small example that worked perfectly! Things can get a bit complicated in native Android! Switching from PhoneGap..

Comment: @Farah hmm... good luck for future programming ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a method and use `View` as the parameter and use it to do do any type of initialization.. like the following:

```
private void initialze(View mView){
TextView taskDetails = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.taskdetails);
taskDetails.setText("trial");
}
```

and use the method in `onCreateView()` like

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState) {
Log.d("changing layout","arabic");
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasklistar, container, false);  
initialze(rootView );
return rootView;
}
```

Its so easy and also following the android programming standard.

Comment: Your code, as neat as it is lol, still causes the same problem, fragment_tasklistar only contains the listview definition but the initialization of the items in the listview is in another layout xml as seen above, is that what is causing the null pointer exception?

Comment: do you want to use the layout from where the textview comes in this fragment? or both layouts in one fragment? clear your requirement first..

Comment: No I do not want them both in one layout, that wouldnt work anyways. What I do want is to set the text from the listfragment class

Comment: i also suggest same as CapDroid said..use your own custom adapter class and put data in text by getView method.

Comment: Thank you, I did use a custom adapter seems like the only way around this.